# Angellist api: How to get to second page of data?

Tags: api, pagination, asp.net-web-api

I was looking at Angel list api (https://angel.co/api) and I noticed a section on pagination. It says entries are limited to max of 50 (for eg. https://api.angel.co/1/users/135/roles has 2 pages work of data but returns only 1 page). The documentation mentions pagination but does not say how to get 2nd page.
Any ideas?

Chetan

Comment: How do you make the HTTP calls? Having difficulty to set it up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747640/simple-https-get-from-the-angellist-api-with-nodejs-and-request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add ?page=2 to the end of the request to get the second page.