# Simple HTTPS GET from the AngelList API with NodeJS and Request

Tags: node.js, oauth, https, httprequest, bearer-token

I have managed to grant access from the user, thus to get the `access_token` as needed to [retrieve the data from the Angellist API](https://angel.co/api/oauth/faq).

The next step is to fetch the user data. As we can read from the Angellist API, you do this by authenticated HTTPS GET requests:

> **Use the Token**
>
> Any requests that require authentication must be made
> using HTTPS, with the access token provided in the HTTP Authorization
> header, request body or query string. AngelList only supports Bearer
> tokens, as defined in
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-08. An example
> using the query string:

```
GET https://api.angel.co/1/me?
    access_token=...
```

To make the request in NodeJS, I use the npm package [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication) as follows:

```
function testRequest(access_token) {
        
        console.log('test request');
        var urltest = "https://api.angel.co/1/me?access_token=" + access_token;
        
        request.get(urltest,
            {
              'auth': {
                'bearer': access_token
              }
            },
          function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log('body', body)
                }
                console.log('body', body)
                console.log('error', error)
            }
        );
};
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
body {"success":false,"error":{"type":"unauthorized","message":"The authenticated user is not authorized for this request."}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the access_token need to be converted or something, i.e. it is not a bearer token?

Comment: Have you tried to use the api in postman or some other client ?

Comment: Returns the same error when I send the request through an url. Not sure how to add bearer tokens with Postman?

Comment: Okay I added in Postman a header: Authorization with value "Bearer 12345token" and it returned the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to send the request as follows:

```
        var optionsGetUserInfo = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://api.angel.co/1/me?access_token=" + access_token",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }

request(optionsGetUserInfo, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        etc...
```

Comment: try removing access_token from url .

Comment: That worked, but it returned the same error: "The authenticated user is not authorized for this request."

Comment: I tried https://api.angel.co/1/me with 'Authorization: Bearer someRandomStr  ' and I got "error: access denied" with "error_description: This access token is invalid or has been revoked by the user". So, I assume that it would work with valid access token.

Comment: The access token should be correct as I retrieve it using the mentioned method. The error is: "... user is not authorized" and not "access token is invalid", meaning that we can assume that the access_token is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that when trying to sign in with another AngelList account, then it works. The account that I tried before was the same as on which I had registered the client app. Not sure why this makes a difference, but it works.